# Group some fixed phrases from a given text to an organised text

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some text (old_text), I want to format it into grouped (new_text). Note that "..." in {{and here...}} means there is more text there.

```
old_text = "Lorem {{here also...}}ipsum dolor sit {{and here...}}amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt {{another here...}}ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. {{some text here...}}Ut enim ad minim{{more text here...}} veniam, quis {{other text here...}} nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat"
```

```
new_text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. ### grouped values ### {{here also...}}{{and here...}}{{another here...}}{{some text here...}}{{more text here...}}{{other text here...}}"
```

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far.

Comment: I have posted the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58887613/3091398). If this answers your question, you may accept my solution as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a regex guru but i have achieved what you need.

```
import re

old_text = "Lorem {{here also...}}ipsum dolor sit {{and here...}}amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt {{another here...}}ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. {{some text here...}}Ut enim ad minim{{more text here...}} veniam, quis {{other text here...}} nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat"

group = re.findall(r'{{(.*?)}}', old_text) # extras whats inside the {{ }}

cleaned = re.sub('\{\{(.*?)\}\}', '', old_text) # extracts text excluding {{ }} and what inside it

new_text = cleaned + "".join("{{" + str + "}}" for str in group)

print(new_text)
```

*Output:*

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis  nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat{{here also...}}{{and here...}}{{another here...}}{{some text here...}}{{more text here...}}{{other text here...}}
```

See it in action [here](https://repl.it/repls/AbleRapidBellsandwhistles)